# Open App on Samsung Gear S when a notification arrives on the Android app

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have been playing around with the notifications relay mechanism and the Socket connections on Samsung Wearables . Using a simple intent , I can relay my notifications to the Wearable but how to open up the app directly when a notification comes on the Host device

Answer (score 0):

Why not use tizen.application.launch() / appControls?

I mean,

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.device.apireference/tizen/application.html#Application

Or

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.appprogramming/html/guide/app_guide/launching_appcontrol.htm

PS: Please don't forget about privileges in your config.xml: